# Convert hugging face audio classifier to TFLite format

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning, huggingface, openai-whisper

I’m making a model to run on an Android phone which will be able to recognise a set of specific audio commands. There are 6 commands, so I need a classifier with 7 classes, one for each command plus a class for anything unrecognised.

To do this, I first took `facebook/wav2vec2-base`, and trained it on a dataset with 1000 examples for each command class, and a further 2000 with “unrecognised” words. The classifier performed excellently.
TFLite seemed the best way of getting the model onto Android, so used optimum to export it to TFLite format (`optimum-cli export tflite --task audio-classification ...`). This wasn’t easy as at first it failed with the error `KeyError: "wav2vec2 (tf_wav2_vec2_for_sequence_classification) is not supported yet with the tflite backend. Only ['onnx'] are supported. If you want to support tflite please propose a PR or open up an issue."`.
Eventually I exported it to onnx, then to tf, and from there to TFLite. The model was too big, ~500MB, so I used dynamic quantisation to get it down to ~100MB. Integer quantisation really messed up the model, so I left it with dynamic quantisation.

I wanted to compare that model with sthg simpler, but `wav2vec2` doesn’t have any “small” or “tiny” variants. Instead I used Whisper, which is intended for ASR (not classification), using the `openai/whisper-tiny` variant. Loaded it using `transformers.WhisperForAudioClassification`, since classification is my goal, and finetuned it on the same dataset. Despite being a lot smaller (30MB) it outperformed the first model - great.

The problem came when trying to export this model (finetuned Whisper model for classification), to TFLite:

- Exporting direct to TFLite (`optimum-cli export tflite --task audio-classification ...`) didn’t work because task `audio-classification` only recognises `Wav2Vec2`. So using it for a Whisper model raises `ValueError: Unrecognized configuration class <class 'transformers.models.whisper.configuration_whisper.WhisperConfig'> for this kind of AutoModel: TFAutoModelForAudioClassification. Model type should be one of Wav2Vec2Config`. Presumed explanation: Whisper is essentially ASR, not a classifier.
- Exporting to ONNX (`optimum-cli export onnx --task audio-classification ...`) didn’t work because `ValueError: Asked to export a whisper model for the task audio-classification, but the Optimum ONNX exporter only supports the tasks feature-extraction, feature-extraction-with-past, automatic-speech-recognition, automatic-speech-recognition-with-past for whisper. Please use a supported task. Please open an issue at https://github.com/huggingface/optimum/issues if you would like the task audio-classification to be supported in the ONNX export for whisper`.

How can I get this model working on Android?